# MVC drop down list input post value and name

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, post, drop-down-menu

I'm writing a form which uses drop down menus for value selection. I'd like to know if it is possible to post `Value` and `Name` of the `SelectList` back to the Controller or add values for every list item? I need to set `LateralityId = Value` and `LateralityName = Text`.

I'll just post some snippets of the code to get the idea across. The model I'm using is

```
public class Condition
{
    public string LateralityName { get; set; }
    public string LateralityId { get; set; }
}
```

and the values are posted with

```
@Html.DropDownListFor( m => m.Condition.LateralityId, GetLateralities() )
```

where

```
    public static List<SelectListItem> GetLateralities()
    {
        return new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "",             Value = "900" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Left",         Value = "1001" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Right",        Value = "1002" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Midline",      Value = "1003" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Left Midline", Value = "1004" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Right Midline",Value = "1005" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Both Sides",   Value = "1006" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Unknown",      Value = "990" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Unspecified",  Value = "997" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "N/A",          Value = "999" },
        };
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Not unless you were to include a hidden input for `LateralityName` and use javascript to handle the `<select>`'s `.change()` event and update the property. But why do you think you would need to do this. If you need the text (unclear why), then just get the text in the POST method based on the  selected `LateralityId` - e.g.  `string text = GetLateralities().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value = LateralityId).Select(x => x.Text);`

Comment: Great. This achieves what I'm looking for. Thank you! I present my solution in an edit of my post.

Comment: Answers should not be in the question. Add your own answer and accept it to close this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution thanks to Stephen Muecke

In the controller I simply use

```
LateralityName = GetLateralities().FirstOrDefault( x => x.Value == m.Condition.LateralityId )?.Text;
```